# Possible to exclude a child from display: grid?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to exclude child elements from a parent with `display: grid`?
I have two different repeating elements in my grid parent. One is the content, and the other is a popup when clicked on the grid element (when clicked, class `hide` will be removed and the element will be visible). Because the element gets visible (`display: block`), it takes a space inside of the grid, which it shouldn't, because it has an absolute / fixed display, which adds just an empty space inside of the grid. Is there any way to do something like `grid-column: none` or so where the element will be excluded from the grid, or be hidden in any kind so it doesn't take up any space?

**EDIT**

I added code and CSS. So you see

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="popup hide"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="popup hide"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <img class="image">
  </div>
  <div class="popup hide"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 19.85vw 19.85vw 19.85vw 19.85vw 19.85vw;
    grid-template-rows: 19.85vw 19.85vw;
    column-gap: 2px;
    row-gap: 2px;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.image {
    width: 100%;
}

.hide {
    display:none;
}
```

Here's the code on codepen https://codepen.io/myusernamealreadyexists/pen/GRoWKwB
(click on the first square, click again on the black background to reset)

Comment: Can you share demo code

Comment: some of your css code would be very helpful

Comment: updated my question and added a codepen

Comment: Your popup from code pen has relative not absolute / fixed. I don't understand what are you trying to do. Please add at least a code or pic of wanted result, so we can compare it with codepen.

Comment: @ikiK When you click on the popup, the red squares have a space between, where the popup is inside the grid. But because the popup has a static display and isn't inside of the grid, it's just white space. https://imgur.com/a/OzgBSwB

Comment: I can see that myself, but what is wanted result?

Comment: @ikiK I want that when the popup is visible, no space gets added to the grid. Just The 3 red squares besides each other, without an added white space.